# What would be the brightest LED that can run all night?

Tags: led

I want to project a small sequence of digits by just putting stencils in front of LEDs. I want this to he bright white and was wondering if I should select a particular type of LED that can last all night and not burn out or heat up fatally.

Comment: this seems like a shopping question and not focused on Electrical engineering.

Comment: Well, I'm a noob without any EE knowledge but kinda DIY type. Sorry for my lack of knowledge as I couldn't speak in technical terms and it sounds consumer-ish. I'll try to find answers somewhere else. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ~~~~= White LED Vf ~= 3V. Small leaded LED Imax = 20 mA so power ~~= 20 mA x 3 V = 60 mW. Light out can be far more than you need.* | If you use a say 6V supply with a series resistor the R drops about 3V. At 20 mA R = V/I = 3/20 mA = 150 Ohms.  If you used eg 4 x NimH AA, capacity is about 2500 mAh so at 20 mA you'd get 2500/20 = 125 hours per charge. 3 x Nimh enough for white LED but has issues with Vbat being too near VLED . Or can use a power pack.  | * eg at 60 mW and 150 lumen/Watt = 9 lumen. A good bright LCD screen backlight is 300 lux = 300 lumen/m^2 so  you can ...

Comment: ... illuminate 9/300 m^2 at 300 lux or about 16" x 16" at screen full brightness = more than you need. So lower mA Ok - larger resistor. Cal also use other battery .

Comment: An LED flashlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any LED can light indefinitely<sup>*</sup> as long as you keep the current within the maximum specified in the datasheet. If you buy a LED without a datasheet, you buy a toy, not a LED, so make sure that you get one. It will have an *Absolute maximum* value, and usually a *recommended operating conditions*.

As for the brightest, no one can answer that but you, nor is it on topic here. There are thousands of suitable LEDs, and a lot of parameters. An answer is soon to be out of date. Your job as a designer is to sift through the options and match them to your requirements and budget.

<sup>*Well... After a couple of decades it may fade.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting with zero knowledge here :) this was helpful